# CoreData: How to refresh "calculated" attributes?

Tags: core-data

My NSFetchedResultsController work great, as long as only "basic" attributes get changed. However if I have a label which is calculated and I'm changing some attributes influencing this label in another view controller on the navigation controller stack, this label doesn't get updated.

For example my label should show the amount of a budget position left saved in the entity SpendingCategory.

```
self.budgetLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [[self.spendingCategory getExpendituresAmount] getLocalizedCurrencyStringWithDigits:0], NSLocalizedString(@"left", nil)];
```

I derive this value from the category on SpendingCategory with this method:

```
- (NSNumber *)getExpendituresAmount
{
    return [self.hasExpenditures valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.amount"];
}
```

However this label doesn't get any updates by the NSFetchedResultsController. And I have several locations in my app where this doesn't happen because a value is calculated. What do I need to change that these updates happen?

**EDIT with datastructure:**
Ok my Spending Category datastructure is roughly (for budget):

```
name (string)
cost (double)
position (integer 16)
Relationsships: hasExpenditures
```

My Expenditures structure (for tracking):

```
amount (double)
date (Date)
description (string)
Relationsships: forSpendingCategory
```

I hope it's clearer now. So why do these values not get updated?

Comment: could you describe your model structure and what does `self.hasExpenditures` holds and gets populated?

Answer (score 1):

The `NSFetchedResultsController` gets tickled when attributes in the relevant `NSManagedObject` instances are updated.  If you are changing something that is purely calculated then the update never fires.  Why is this relevant?

If you are changing something in the Expenditures entity (btw, entities should be singular in name) and you are watching the Spending Category entity then the `NSFetchedResultsController` won't fire because you didn't change anything that is relevant.

How to fix this?

Depends.  I normally keep that *derived* value in the entity and persist it.  Further, whenever a child changes a relevant value, I have the parent recalculate.  This will cause the `NSFetchedResultsController` to fire.

How do you watch the values?

Either you have the child call a method on the parent (icky) or you have the parent watch the values on its children via KVO (better).  Your personal preference decides here.

### Update 1

To keep the derived value in the entity you add a new attributed to the entity and store it.  Nothing is special about the attribute.  It helps to keep in mind that Core Data is **not a database**.  Core Data is your data model that happens to persist to a database if you so choose.  Therefore you want to **denormalize** the database in cases like this.

while I was searching SO to find a good link for watching children, I stumbled across this example.

[KVO object properties within to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336982/kvo-object-properties-within-to-many-relationship)

While the accepted answer is not very good, the second answer, using a `NSFetchedResultsController` is quite interesting and is worth exploring.  The basic idea is that your parent objects instantiate a `NSFetchedResultsController` on `-awakeFromFetch` or `-awakeFromInsert` and when it fires, they recalculate the derived value.  Thus the value is always up to date and your view controller based `NSFetchedResultController` instances will fire because the parent object has changed.

Comment: Hm ok and could you give an example how to watch the values via KVO? And and example an how you keep a derived value in the entity? Still a coredata newbie, so I'm happy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similiar time  ago, basically you need to store your calculated value in a transient attribute in your CoreData model, rather than implement your own setter and getter. Then in the related NSManagedObject you need to implement two methods:

```
// this will populate the values when 
// the entity is retrieved from the store
-(void)awakeFromFetch {
  [self refreshCellInfo];
}

// this will refresh the values when
// the object goes to fault
// (for example when it is off screen)
-(void)willTurnIntoFault {
  [self refreshCellInfo];
}

-(void)refreshCellInfo {
  // update all your derived values...
}
```